# Splitting assets: Options for managing asset IDs and related records

Tags: gis, uniqueidentifier, business-rules, maximo, data-integrity

I have road assets in a GIS layer (spatial table in an Oracle [geodatabase](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/what-is-a-geodatabase.htm)).

[image]

Roads are split into separate lines/records where they intersect. This is an established business rule that cannot be changed.

Each road has work order records in a related table (in Maximo 7.6.1.1) that pertain to a point along the road.

**Scenario:**

A new road (#200) has been built that intersects an existing road (#100). Road #100 needs to be split into two separate roads at the intersection of road #200 (this is accomplished using GIS editing tools).

**Question:**

What are the options for managing the the road IDs and the related work order records?

Answer (score 0):

Here are the options that I can think of:

**Option 1:**

Decommission the current road (#100) using the `status` field and create two new roads (#101 and #102).

- The work order history will remain associated with the decommissioned road, not the new roads.
- The `road ID` of the decommissioned asset could be stored in a `decom_road_id` field in the new roads.

**Option 2:**

Split the current road (#100). Keep the existing `road_id` for the section on the left-hand side (#100) and create a new `road ID` for the section on the right-hand side (#101).

- The work order history will remain associated with the existing road (#100).
- This means that the work order records on the right-hand side of the road will have **incorrect** `road_ids`.

**Option 3:**

Same as option 2, except we correct the `road_id` of the work orders on the right-hand side (to #101).